# Ruby Gem or Rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a gem that requires rails as a dependency (for using Rails methods like underscore, camelize and others).

Is 'gem' still a gem or is it now something else (Rails Plugin?) since I have rails as a dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to depend on Rails as a whole (in fact if it really is a standalone gem, I would recommend that you do not) you can depend on just the parts of it that provide the functionality you need, in this case you are talking about [ActiveSupport](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport).

Comment: Agreed, I would only require the entire rails stack if your gem is specifically targetted at enhancing RoR applications - Yours definitely sounds like it only needs `ActiveSupport` as ctcherry mentioned.